# How can I add properties to a react component passed as a variable?

Tags: reactjs

My scenario is that I'm creating a render() function in a controller (not React related) to render views with the option of specifying a layout. That way I can have multiple different layout components, all accepting a content property, that can be rendered in a simple way. Here's what I'm trying to do in a nutshell:

```
render: function(content, layout) {
    layout = layout || <Layout />;
    layout.setProps({ content: content });
    React.render(layout, document.body);
}
```

Can it be done? Or if you think it can be done but it's a bad idea, please let me know why.

Comment: does this all take place in the jsx script tag?

Comment: No, in my case this is happening in a controller outside of React.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could approach this.

The simplest is to pass the layout's type and properties separately:

```
function render(content, layoutType, layoutProperties) {
  layoutType = layoutType || Layout;
  layoutProperties = layoutProperties || {};

  var props = { content: content };
  for (var key in layoutProperties) {
    props[key] = layoutProperties[key];
  }

  var layout = React.createElement(layoutType, props);

  React.render(layout, document.body);
}

render(<div>Test 1</div>);
render(<div>Test 2</div>, CustomLayout, { title: "Test Title" });
```

<sup>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/hjLufbkz/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/hjLufbkz/</sup>

If you want to pass a fully-realized `ReactElement` as the layout instead, you could use [`React.addons.cloneWithProps`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/clone-with-props.html) (or, in v0.13 RC2 and later, [`React.cloneElement`](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement)):

```
function render(content, layout) {
  var props = { content: content };
  layout = layout || <Layout />;
  layout = React.addons.cloneWithProps(layout, props);

  React.render(layout, document.body);
}

render(<div>Test 1</div>);
render(<div>Test 2</div>, <CustomLayout title="Test Title" />);
```

<sup>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/8krawhx4/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/8krawhx4/</sup>

---

I'm a big fan of using `this.props.children` to nest elements; note that you can modify both the techniques above to do so:

```
function render(content, layoutType, layoutProperties) {
  layoutType = layoutType || Layout;
  layoutProperties = layoutProperties || {};

  var layout = React.createElement(layoutType, layoutProperties, content);

  React.render(layout, document.body);
}
```

<sup>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/6g8uyfp4/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/6g8uyfp4/</sup>

and

```
function render(content, layout) {
  layout = layout || <Layout>{content}</Layout>;
  layout = React.addons.cloneWithProps(layout, {children: content});

  React.render(layout, document.body);
}
```

<sup>[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/nadv297h/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/nadv297h/</sup>

Of course, if one of your custom layout components already utilizes `this.props.children` for other purposes, the original technique with `cloneWithProps`/`cloneElement` and `this.props.content` works just fine. ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/b5ncfnqh/): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/b5ncfnqh/)

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer. I found out that the following works:

render: function(content, layout) {
    layout = layout || <Layout />;
    layout.props.content = content;
    React.render(layout, document.body);
}

However, from what I read, props is supposed to be an immutable property, so I guess this would be bad practice. I'll adopt one of the methods you suggested instead.

Comment: Good call; I also believe in a future version of React, props really *will* be immutable.

Comment: Use `React.cloneElement()` instead, since `React.addons.cloneWithProps()` is deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html